# java swing set background color of whole tabbedpane

Tags: swing

My problem is described in this image:

[image]

Comment: It's tough, since the Background Color will depend on the type of LookAndFeel used by you. On Metal LAF, you can change the colour of the TAB, but not that of the content Area. But if you will change it to the Windows, then the colour of the Content Area is something you can change/see, but in this case Tab colour won't change.

Answer (score 1):

If `setBackground(Color.x)` function didn't work for you, you can try `setBackgroundAt()` function as in [TabComponents demo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html#eg)

```
private void initTabComponent(int i) {
    pane.setTabComponentAt(i, new ButtonTabComponent(pane));
    pane.setBackgroundAt(i, Color.orange);
}
```

Note: Make sure that the target component is opaque